# Order by boolean

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a `products` table and it contains column `on_sale` and it is defined as `tinyint` or `boolean`.
So if it has value `1` in database or `true` in this case, then it is sale product and alternatively `0` or `false` is not a sales product.
I want to display them in order that sales products are first and the the rest of them. So in this case all products with value `true` / `1` are displayed first.

The problem is that I can not get it done with built  in `order` method.

Here is my code so far:

```
          $products = $products->find('all',$this->filterConditions($display))           
            ->where(function (QueryExpression $exp, Query $q) use ($productIds) {
                return $exp->in('id', $productIds);
            });

        /*** Paginate */
        $this->products = $this->Paginator->paginate($products, [
            'limit' => 18,
        ]);
```

And then the filter conditions function

```
 protected function filterConditions($display)
    {
        $conditions = [];

        switch ($display){
            case 'ASC' :
                $conditions['order'] = 'price ASC';
                break;
            case 'DESC' :
                $conditions['order'] = 'price DESC';
                break;
            case 'saleproducts' :
                $conditions['order'] = 'on_sale DESC';
                break;
            default : $conditions['order'] = '-priority DESC';
        }

        return $conditions;
    }
```

`ASC` , `DESC` and `priority` ordering is working fine but it doesn`t work with `on_sale`

I noticed that if I remove this part

```
->where(function (QueryExpression $exp, Query $q) use ($productIds) {
                return $exp->in('id', $productIds);
            });
```

Then ordering works fine.
The only problem is that I need those `$productIds` - that is `array` btw

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: In what way is not working? How does it get sorted when you try that? Does it do the default (by priority)?

Comment: No...not even default...if I change on_sale = > Desc and on_sale => Asc it changes some product order but not in the right order.

Comment: Have you tested the query directly on the database to determine whether your query building is at fault or the database behaviour is weird to begin with?

Comment: I found out that if I remove this part:
->where(function (QueryExpression $exp, Query $q) use ($productIds) {
                return $exp->in('id', $productIds);
            });
Everything works fine.

Edited my question